# wpf inkcanvas stroke erase by pixel

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, pixel

I'm developing drawing tool control using inkcanvs in wpf.
When i draw rectangle, this is original image.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qIPW.jpg)

And i set that editing mode is erase by point. When i erase rectangle, this is image after working.

[Erased Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LXH1.jpg)

I want that erase function works as well as default drawing tool in windows. It would be worked by pixel. Erase shape by pixel.

Part of Source Codes

```
public class Label : Stroke
{
protected override void DrawCore(DrawingContext drawingContext, DrawingAttributes drawingAttributes)

Rect rect = new Rect((Point)this.StylusPoints[0], (Point)this.StylusPoints[1]);

drawingContext.DrawRectangle(...)
```

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Thank you for your help :) I almost waste my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard API.

Only by translating an ink image (strokes, which are enhanced vectors) to a bitmap image (which contains pixels) individual pixels can be manipulated but the stroke information will be lost.

With quite some effort an application could be created that keeps track of all its user's actions (draw some strokes, add a pixel, remove a pixel) and replays them all every time the UI needs a redraw, injecting the transformation from vector to bitmap where needed.

This is a nice exercise but might prove to be too slow and/or complex.